# Wxwidgets use thread for background proccess

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I need help about how to use thread. I'm using wxsmith and codeblock.
i want to make my program keep writing text into textctrl, but it makes my program not responding. then i found out that i need to use thread but i don't know how to do it.
i've followed this tutorial https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/WxSmith_tutorial:_Keyboard_Input_and_Displaying_Results to make me able to use print function on textctrl.
my code looks like this :
testwxthreadMain.h

```
#ifndef TESTWXTHREADMAIN_H
#define TESTWXTHREADMAIN_H

//(*Headers(testwxthreadFrame)
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/panel.h>
#include <wx/statusbr.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
//*)

class testwxthreadFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:

        testwxthreadFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id = -1);
        virtual ~testwxthreadFrame();
        friend void printg(char *fmt, ...);

    private:

        //(*Handlers(testwxthreadFrame)
        void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
        //*)

        //(*Identifiers(testwxthreadFrame)
        static const long ID_TEXTCTRL1;
        static const long ID_BUTTON1;
        static const long ID_PANEL1;
        static const long idMenuQuit;
        static const long idMenuAbout;
        static const long ID_STATUSBAR1;
        //*)

        //(*Declarations(testwxthreadFrame)
        wxButton* Button1;
        wxPanel* Panel1;
        wxStatusBar* StatusBar1;
        wxTextCtrl* TextCtrl1;
        //*)

        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

#endif // TESTWXTHREADMAIN_H
```

testwxthreadApp.cpp

```
#include "testwxthreadApp.h"

//(*AppHeaders
#include "testwxthreadMain.h"
#include <wx/image.h>
//*)

IMPLEMENT_APP(testwxthreadApp);

testwxthreadFrame* MainFrame;

bool testwxthreadApp::OnInit()
{
    //(*AppInitialize
    bool wxsOK = true;
    wxInitAllImageHandlers();
    if ( wxsOK )
    {
         MainFrame = new testwxthreadFrame(0);
        MainFrame->Show();
        SetTopWindow(MainFrame);
    }
    //*)
    return wxsOK;

}
```

testwxthreadMain.cpp

```
#include <wx\thread.h>
#include "testwxthreadMain.h"
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>
extern testwxthreadFrame* MainFrame;
//(*InternalHeaders(testwxthreadFrame)
#include <wx/intl.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
//*)

//helper functions
enum wxbuildinfoformat {
    short_f, long_f };

wxString wxbuildinfo(wxbuildinfoformat format)
{
    wxString wxbuild(wxVERSION_STRING);

    if (format == long_f )
    {
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Windows");
#elif defined(__UNIX__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Linux");
#endif

#if wxUSE_UNICODE
        wxbuild << _T("-Unicode build");
#else
        wxbuild << _T("-ANSI build");
#endif // wxUSE_UNICODE
    }

    return wxbuild;
}

//(*IdInit(testwxthreadFrame)
const long testwxthreadFrame::ID_TEXTCTRL1 = wxNewId();
const long testwxthreadFrame::ID_BUTTON1 = wxNewId();
const long testwxthreadFrame::ID_BUTTON2 = wxNewId();
const long testwxthreadFrame::ID_PANEL1 = wxNewId();
const long testwxthreadFrame::idMenuQuit = wxNewId();
const long testwxthreadFrame::idMenuAbout = wxNewId();
const long testwxthreadFrame::ID_STATUSBAR1 = wxNewId();
//*)

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(testwxthreadFrame,wxFrame)
    //(*EventTable(testwxthreadFrame)
    //*)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

testwxthreadFrame::testwxthreadFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(testwxthreadFrame)
    wxMenu* Menu1;
    wxMenu* Menu2;
    wxMenuBar* MenuBar1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem1;
    wxMenuItem* MenuItem2;

    Create(parent, id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
    Panel1 = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL1, wxPoint(144,120), wxSize(400,240), wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    TextCtrl1 = new wxTextCtrl(Panel1, ID_TEXTCTRL1, wxEmptyString, wxPoint(80,24), wxSize(264,144), wxTE_MULTILINE, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TEXTCTRL1"));
    Button1 = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON1, _("test"), wxPoint(168,184), wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    Button2 = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON2, _("About"), wxPoint(168,232), wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON2"));
    MenuBar1 = new wxMenuBar();
    Menu1 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem1 = new wxMenuItem(Menu1, idMenuQuit, _("Quit\tAlt-F4"), _("Quit the application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu1->Append(MenuItem1);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu1, _("&File"));
    Menu2 = new wxMenu();
    MenuItem2 = new wxMenuItem(Menu2, idMenuAbout, _("About\tF1"), _("Show info about this application"), wxITEM_NORMAL);
    Menu2->Append(MenuItem2);
    MenuBar1->Append(Menu2, _("Help"));
    SetMenuBar(MenuBar1);
    StatusBar1 = new wxStatusBar(this, ID_STATUSBAR1, 0, _T("ID_STATUSBAR1"));
    int __wxStatusBarWidths_1[1] = { -1 };
    int __wxStatusBarStyles_1[1] = { wxSB_NORMAL };
    StatusBar1->SetFieldsCount(1,__wxStatusBarWidths_1);
    StatusBar1->SetStatusStyles(1,__wxStatusBarStyles_1);
    SetStatusBar(StatusBar1);

    Connect(ID_BUTTON1,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testwxthreadFrame::OnButton1Click);
    Connect(ID_BUTTON2,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testwxthreadFrame::OnAbout);
    Connect(idMenuQuit,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testwxthreadFrame::OnQuit);
    Connect(idMenuAbout,wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&testwxthreadFrame::OnAbout);
    //*)
}

testwxthreadFrame::~testwxthreadFrame()
{
    //(*Destroy(testwxthreadFrame)
    //*)
}

void testwxthreadFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close();
}

void testwxthreadFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxString msg = wxbuildinfo(long_f);
    wxMessageBox(msg, _("Welcome to..."));
}

void printg(char *fmt, ...);

void number(int z){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    z++;
    printg("%d \n", z);
    }
}

void test(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  printg("%s", "Text1\n");
  number(100);
}
}

void print(){
 printg("%s", "Start\n");
}

void testwxthreadFrame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    print();
    test();
}




#define MAXPRINTOUT 500
#define MAXLINE 500
#define OK 1
#define ERR -1

char printout[MAXPRINTOUT], inbufAsRead[MAXLINE], inbuf[MAXLINE], *pinbuf;

void printg(char *fmt, ...){
    char buf[240];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    short lenb, lenp;
    lenb = strlen(buf);
    lenp = strlen(printout);
    if(lenb+lenp >= MAXPRINTOUT-2){
        wxString wxPO(printout, wxConvUTF8);
        MainFrame->TextCtrl1->AppendText(wxPO);
        printout[0] = '\0';
        }
    strcat(printout, buf);
    lenp = strlen(printout);
    // If the last character in printout is \n, then it is time to
    // print
    if(printout[lenp-1] == '\n'){
        // convert printout to a wxString, which we will call wxPO
        wxString wxPO(printout, wxConvUTF8);
        MainFrame->TextCtrl1->AppendText(wxPO);
        printout[0] = '\0';
        }
     }
```

I'm using wxsmith to generate the some code. When i run the program, and then i press the button, my program freeze and not responding. how can i make thread to this proccess :

```
void testwxthreadFrame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
  printg("%s", "O brave new world!\n");
}
```

Comment: nothing will happen - you event table is empty. also you shuold look at the thread sample and documentation of wxThred class.

Comment: @Igor: Seems like he/she is using `Connect`.

Comment: @anonymous: I suggest you take a look at wxTimer (https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_timer.html)

Comment: This guys tutorials are really good. The one on std::thread https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DANoG48yFww&t=13s

Comment: @macroland, and official documentation and sample are even better.

Comment: alright, i'll look at the documentation, sample, and tutorial about thread first. thank you.

Comment: @Igor I just want to make sure, so if i change the loop into a function like void test(), i need to add it to event table right?

Comment: @anonymous, it depenmds on what you want to achieve. Run that code in a thread or in a timer...

Comment: @Igor i want to run the code in a thread, do i need to add the function to event table?

Comment: @anonymous, no you need to make this function a thread function. and then start a thread in the button handler.

Comment: @Igor i see, but what if the button event have a lot of function inside it, like when i press the button, there'll be several function running. So i need to make the function into thread function right?

Comment: @anonymous, post some code or CLEARLY explain what do you mean. You can create a thread that will execute many different functions or 1 function. It all depends on what you are looking for to do. Also, please remember - NO CALLS TO THE GUI FROM A SECONDARY THREAD!!!!!

Comment: @Igor I've put some function on button1 click event, there are 2 loop function. Do i need to make these 2 functions into 2 thread function? 
Sorry if the example code is bad. what i'm trying to make is a program that capture all packet networks, and then show it into a table, and then put some important data into database, but the code is too much so i tried to make an example to see what i have to do.

Comment: @anonymous, I think you will be better off playing with the dissector in the Wireshark and just trying to use SQLite API to store the data in the DB. Might be waaay simpler and easier.